# What is the relationship between solvable, nilpotent and transfer homomorphism?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, transfer-theory

I know some facts such as:
Nilpotent groups are solvable, $p$-groups are nilpotent, a finite group whose order is a product of distinct primes is solvable, and finite groups are nilpotent if and only if it is a finite product of solvable groups.

Are there any other major relationships between these concepts that one should be aware of?

Also, how do you compute a transfer? Could you provide a simple example or two?

Comment: Have you heard of the M-groups? If not, I recommend [the book](http://www.amazon.com/Character-Theory-Finite-Groups-Mathematics/dp/0486680142/ref=la_B001HMLSW4_1_3?ie=UTF8&qid=1355314566&sr=1-3)

Comment: Not every product of solvable groups is nilpotent, for example $S_3 \times \mathbb{Z}_2$ is not nilpotent. However, it is true that a finite group is nilpotent if and only if it is the product of its Sylow subgroups.

Comment: You want to read the book "Between nilpotent and solvable" by Henry G. Bray and Michael Weinstein. The whole book is about a big hierarchy of notions that lie between the two in the title. This includes M-groups, equichained groups, and others.

Comment: It is not true that all $p$-groups are nilpotent.

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/a/205805/12952 This earlier answer of mine may help you with the first part.

Comment: Probably, he thinks that all groups are finite. For me that's also true ;-)